# XMLHttpRequest and images

Tags: image, xmlhttprequest

I'm building a web page with a grid of images which are loaded using XMLHttpRequest to call the html for a grid of images. The images are all enclosed in a div "image_grid". Image_grid is of variable height, depending on the number of images downloaded (using a mySQL query).

Everything works fine and the image_grid displays correctly, save that on the page that the images are loaded into I have a "footer" div.

I cannot get the footer to display below of the div that contains the images. It always displays just below the header with the images over top of it.

My page layout is:

1. header div (which calls the image_grid HTML using XMLHttpRequest and PHP-mySQL)
2. ajax div (to which the image_grid is attached using innerHTML and http.responseText)
3. footer div (which, after the Ajax request, never positions itself at the bottom of the page below the image grid)

As far as I can tell, the problem may be be caused because the image_grid is initialized before the images are actually downloaded and so the footer is never positioned correctly.

After http.responseText, using Javascript, I can calculate and set the the "correct" height of the image_grid by querying the number of images in the grid, but it has no effect on the position of the footer div which always remains immediately below the header div and hidden under the image_grid.

There is obviously no callback event in XMLHttpRequest for when the called HTML, including called images, is actually fully loaded. XMLHttpRequest seems to work fine for fixed height divs, but not for divs of "random" height that are loaded using http.responseText?

I'd appreciate some advice on this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any stylesheets? If so, what are the styles on the footer div? It sounds like the CSS should take care of the positioning for you.